# OpenCV en python no reconoce los modulos?

Tags: python, vscode, opencv

Este es el código:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey1(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

El problema es que no logro que funcione, ¿creo que esta todo bien instalado?

Comment: Tienes que usar las etiquetas adecuada, por ejemplo si no usas vscode entonces tu respuesta no tiene sentido

Comment: las etiquetas están bien, quizás me falto agregar json..

Comment: ¿ *json* ? ¿por qué quieres agregar esa etiqueta? Si te das cuenta yo he agregado la etiqueta vscode, Te recomiendo leer [ask], [answer] y pasar el [tour]

Answer (score 1):

encontré la solución, tengo que agregar un argumento en el archivo settings.json

```
python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los códigos tanto de la pregunta como de la respuesta van como texto por favor